# how to remove request header from HttpInputStream

Tags: file, servlets, httprequest, fileinputstream

I need help with a servlet.

I need to read a inputStream in one request and write a tiff file.
The inputStream come with request header and i dont know how remove that bytes and write only the file.

See initial bytes from the writen file.

```
-qF3PFkB8oQ-OnPe9HVzkqFtLeOnz7S5Be
Content-Disposition: form-data; name=""; filename=""
Content-Type: application/octet-stream; charset=ISO-8859-1
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
```

I want to remove that and write only bytes from the tiff file.
PS: sender of file its not me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apache commons solve 90% of your problems... only need know what keywords use in search :) 
"parse multipart request"
and google say:
http://www.oreillynet.com/onjava/blog/2006/06/parsing_formdata_multiparts.html

```
int boundaryIndex = contentType.indexOf("boundary=");
byte[] boundary = (contentType.substring(boundaryIndex + 9)).getBytes();

ByteArrayInputStream input = new ByteArrayInputStream(buffer.getBytes());
MultipartStream multipartStream =  new MultipartStream(input, boundary);

boolean nextPart = multipartStream.skipPreamble();
while(nextPart) {
  String headers = multipartStream.readHeaders();
  System.out.println("Headers: " + headers);
  ByteArrayOutputStream data = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
  multipartStream.readBodyData(data);
  System.out.println(new String(data.toByteArray());

  nextPart = multipartStream.readBoundary();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you're not using HttpServletRequest's getInputStream() method to get the content without its headers, either way you have the option to start reading the input stream and ignoring the content until you find two consecutive CRLF's, which defines the end of the headers.

One way of doing that is like this:

```
String headers = new java.util.Scanner(inputStream).next("\\r\\n\\r\\n");
// Read rset of input stream
```

Comment: i using the getInputStream() and read whit a 'BufferedInputStream' using a byte[] buffer ... but in inputStream comes the header. i will try use java.util.Scanner

Comment: i tryed scanner.
that help-me in remove that first lines with "\\r\\n\\r\\n"
but my tiff not work.
i think my inputStream is all the body of request.

in last line of written file of stream has the same code of first line "-qF3PFkB8oQ-OnPe9HVzkqFtLeOnz7S5Be". If it was, i just need to learn how i read stream as a body and get from the body my file bytes

Answer (score 0):

For me I use annotation and parameter like this:

```
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
```

> public Response testUpload(File uploadedInputStream)

And then I can read the file content with:

```
 byte[] totalBytes = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(uploadedInputStream.toURI()));
```

Then I have to ignore the first 4 lines, also the end-of-content part, like this:

```
int headerLen = 0;
int index = 0;
while(totalBytes[index] != '\n' && index < totalBytes.length) {
    headerLen++;
    index++;
}
            
//ignore next three line
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    index++;
    while (totalBytes[index] != '\n' && index < totalBytes.length) {
        index++;
    }
}
index++;
out.write(totalBytes, index, totalBytes.length - index - (headerLen+3));
out.flush();
out.close();
```